# Create Special Price Product Listing CMS page in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Hi there how can i create a CMS page in magento which will display all the active and in stock special price Product same as catalog listing.

Comment: Checkout the following url to do so.

http://www.creativemediagroup.net/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/27-magento-show-only-special-priced-products-in-a-category

Answer (score 0):

In your cms page call your block code
{{block type="test/test" name="test" template="test/test.phtml"}}

Now In your product collection add following filter:
$collection->joinField('is_in_stock',
                    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                    'is_in_stock',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                    'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => ''));